# Using Knockout to restrict non-numeric input on keypress

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'd like to use knockout (not specifically jQuery or any other jQuery libraries) to restrict non-numeric input on inputs (on keypress).  I have many numeric input fields so the solution should be easy to apply to other Knockout observables/inputs.

How should I go about this?

Thanks,

Comment: Attach an event handler for the `keypress` event (or other) through the [event](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html) binding.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before using the subscribe callback on an observable. The feature is outlined here http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly_subscribing_to_observables

So you could could do something like:

```
var myNonNumericObservable = ko.observable();
myNonNumericObservable.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    var strippedValue = newValue.replace(/\D/g,'');
    if (strippedValue != newValue) {
        myNonNumericObservable(strippedValue);
    }
});
```